# Is there a gallery of QGIS maps anywhere?

Tags: qgis, cartography, style

Specifically, I want to see the gorgeous map of Chugach State Park that you see when starting QGIS 2.4 "Chugiak". Is there a website out there where people share maps? I would like to share and see others' styles and ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a [Flicker group](https://www.flickr.com/groups/qgis/pool/). See also, [the Screenshots page](http://qgis.org/en/site/about/screenshots.html) on the QGIS.org site for latest samples of maps.

Not sure about the Chugach State Park map. Generally, the splash screen map is of a specific area, but not necessarily produced with QGIS.